Set selected values in multi-select drop-down list in .net core 8
In my .Net 8 form, I have a multi-select drop-down list. The selected values are stored in the DB as a string delimited by commas e.g. A,B,C. How should I bind selected values to my drop-down list?
Here is my model:
public partial class Bat
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? MyMultiSelectList { get; set; } = null!; 
}

Here is my code for Edit method
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var bat = await _context.Bats.FindAsync(id);
    List<string> selectedBats = bat.MyMultiSelectList.Split(",").ToList();
    List<SelectListItem> batList = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem(){Text="A", Value="A"},
        new SelectListItem(){Text="B", Value="B"},
        new SelectListItem(){Text="C", Value="C"}
    };

    ViewBag.BatList =  new SelectList(batList, "Value", "Text", selectedBats);

    if (initiative == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(bat);
}

My Edit view contains
<select asp-for="MyMultiSelectList" asp-items="ViewBag.BatList" class="form-select form-select-sm shadow-none" multiple></select>

How do I set selected values in this mutli-select dropdwon list?

Here is a working sample for you, @avinash's suggestion is correct, but we still need to add somthing in Edit.cshtml, you can check the test result first, and you can find my test code below.


BatController/Edit Method.
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var bat = await _context.Bats.FindAsync(id);
    List<string> selectedBats = bat.MyMultiSelectList.Split(",").ToList();
    List<SelectListItem> batList = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem(){Text="A", Value="A"},
        new SelectListItem(){Text="B", Value="B"},
        new SelectListItem(){Text="C", Value="C"}
    };

    ViewBag.BatList =  new SelectList(batList, "Value", "Text", selectedBats);

    if (initiative == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    foreach (var item in selectList)
    {
        if (selectedBats.Contains(item.Value))
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }

    ViewData["BatList"] = selectList;
    return View(bat);
}

Edit.cshtml
@model WebApplication5.Models.Bat

<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MyMultiSelectList" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="MyMultiSelectList" class="form-select form-select-sm shadow-none" multiple>
            @foreach (var item in (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["BatList"])
            {
                @if (item.Selected)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Value" selected>@item.Text</option>
                }
                else
                {
                    <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="MyMultiSelectList" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>


You need to iterate through the bat list and set the selected property to true.
foreach (var item in batList)
    {
        if (selectedBats.Contains(item.Value))
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
ViewBag.BatList = batList;

Then you can use the bind statement for your multiselect.


<select asp-for="MyMultiSelectList" asp-items="ViewBag.BatList" class="form-select form-select-sm shadow-none" multiple></select>




When I debug, I see ViewBag.BatList contains SelectListItem with Selected set to true but when the view is rendered I see multi-select drop-down list but without any selection.  For some reason asp-items="ViewBag.BatList" dosen't set the selected values.
